# unable to align div in center in Bootstrap v3.1.1

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Am using `Bootstrap v3.1.1` and try to align div to center but unable to align div to center

this is my page code i need the for to be in center of page but unable to do this can some one help me to algin form in center

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Animus A Blogging Category Flat Bootstarp Resposive Website Template | Home :: w3layouts</title>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="keywords" content="Graphic Responsive web template, Bootstrap Web Templates, Flat Web Templates, Andriod Compatible web template, 
              Smartphone Compatible web template, free webdesigns for Nokia, Samsung, LG, SonyErricsson, Motorola web design" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="contact-top">
            <div class="container">
                <h2>Log in</h2>     
                <div class="contact">
                    <p></p>
                    <div class="contact-down">
                        <div class="col-md-6 contact-info" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;">
                            <form>
                                <input type="text" name="your name" placeholder="USER NAME" class="input"><br><br>
                                <input type="password" name="your email" placeholder="PASSWORD" class="input">
                                <div class="clearfix"> </div>
                                <input type="submit"value="SEND" />
                            </form>                 
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"> </div>

                    </div>
                </div>  
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you add col-md-offset-3 Contact-info div as follows

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 contact-info">
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="your name" placeholder="USER NAME" class="input"><br><br>
    <input type="password" name="your email" placeholder="PASSWORD" class="input">
    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
   <input type="submit"value="SEND" />
  </form>                 
</div>
```

Comment: its not working for you because you have added style = " margin-right:auto; margin-left:auto" . please remove that

Answer (score 0):

Set a width on the div.

```
<div class="col-md-6 contact-info" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;width:600px;">
```

Comment: I tried the code in several browsers. It centers both the input fields to the center of the page. Maybe one of the two css files your including is overwriting it? Can you remove them and try.